# Android In-App Billing or Sandbox

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have a problem related to In-app billing v3 (**Sandbox**). I've uploaded the application and defined gmail accounts for testing and create **In-app product** with specific Product Id: **light_armor** and **ACTIVATE** the product items. When I tried the sample application given (attached) together with the "**Google Play Billing Library**" which is located in "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\play_billing" or downloaded into  Android SDK manager Which is the name of the sample app there is **TRIVAL DRIVE**.

When using the reserved product Id e.g "***android.test.purchased***" and other 3 reserved product id's. It works properly but when I tried to implement the Product Id that I've created where the status is **ACTIVE** it gives the error of "***This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information.***"

I have waited more than 24 hours to see if it's really worked well but it give me this error. I assume that google gives the exact example of In-app billing.

Questions:

1. Does google play testing purchase affect by the type of carrier you have?
2. Does the app really need to be published in order to test the In-app product items?
3. I've declared the product Id as **light_armor** only, does it necessary to include the package name on it? like **com.example.inappbilling.light_armor**.

Sorry for my Bad english.. I hope you would help me. Thank you . ^_^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answers:**

- May be not, i don't find anything about anywhere saying in app purchase carrier dependent.
- App doesn't need to be published for testing in app purchase, only **items** needed to be **active**.
- You only set the product id as your wish by following **convention**. It will be automatically reflected as `com.example.test:item`.

  **In-app Product ID**

  Product IDs are unique across an application's namespace. A product ID must start with a lowercase letter or a number, and must be composed using only lowercase letters (a-z), numbers (0-9), underlines (_), and dots (.). The product ID "android.test" is reserved, as are all product IDs that start with "android.test."
      In addition, you cannot modify an item's product ID after it is created, and you cannot reuse a product ID.

These are the procedure for adding and testing in app purchase which works in my case --

- **First**  You have to create a **signed apk** then uploade it to play store  and save as draft. Remember what **product id** you used in your code as **item product id**, you will need this next step.
- **Second** Add a new product in **In-app Products**, **set** the **product id** of this item according to that id which you added in code and set it to **Active**.
- **Third** Add the tester account in **developer console** and distribute **this signed apk** to those people for testing. If you don't distribute that signed apk then you will always get

  **"This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play. Check the help center for more information."**

  error as the app by which you are trying to test the in app purchase doesn't contain the same finger print which is in **developer console**.

Comment: Thanks for your wise and immediate answer Chinmoy Debnath. I will try this procedure of your's. Thanks again.

Comment: As per your first point remeber product id but i had not put any product id i had just put sampleapps code put all permision sing apk and upload on market but it will not allow me to add product id in inapp purchase